# 3-column layout fails in absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, layout

IMHO the following is the typical 3-column-layout using CSS. Without the surrounding #main-div it looks OK.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #main {
            position: absolute;
            left: 100px;
            top: 100px;
            /* width: 400px; */
        }
        .blue {
            height: 30px;
            background-color: blue;
            float:right;
        }
        .green {
            height: 30px;
            background-color: green;
        }
        .red {
            height: 30px;
            background-color: red;
            float: right;
        }
    </style>    
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div>
        <div class="blue">RIGHT</div>
        <div class="red">MIDDLE</div>
        <div class="green">LEFT</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="blue">RIGHT</div>
        <div class="red">MIDDLE ####</div>
        <div class="green">LEFT</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="blue">RIGHT</div>
        <div class="red">############### IN THE MIDDLE</div>
        <div class="green">LEFT</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

If you make the window very small or add the #main-div the last "LEFT" drops out of the layout. I can give it a sufficient width and it works again, but I was asking myself if I can tell the browser to let the width of the middle-column dictate the width of the #main-div, so that the third LEFT isn't kicked out and the whole div is not wider than necessary?

I don't want to calculate this with JavaScript...:(

Comment: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u743W/)**. Did you really want it to look like a staircase?

Comment: Why do you think you need absolute positioning for #main?

Comment: When it's ready it should become a right-aligned menu, that is placed where the mousepointer sits. What is left and right is of fixed width, but I cant't tell about the menu-items text in the middle, so it will have a ragged margin (staircase-look). It's always a bit hard to get the width of a text with JavaScript when it is not already visible in the browser, so it would be really nice if I don't have to deal with it at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
.green {float:left;}
div {height:30px;}
```

does this help?